# Do I need focus on testing "public" methods or "private" methods in JUnit test?

Tags: java, testing, junit

are most of the JUnit test written for public methods or private methods? Which do I need to focus on if I have not so much time?

Comment: 1. You always need to have time for tests. If you don't, then you are doing it wrong.  
2. Test everything, starting with public methods.

Comment: This is a testing methodology question, so it probably belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: If you need to test private methods in order to get complete coverage, then you need to refactor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should to test everything that forms part of the API. Unless you're using reflection, this means the public/protected and package level methods.

Clearly, this is opinion. But it is one based on experience. Let me take my opinion further.

Ideally, you should practice test-driven development. In this practice you:

1. Write the tests first, including in them the public methods of the test subject that you *wish* to have. This helps you devise a useful API.
2. Then you write just enough code to make the tests pass. This will leave you with 100% coverage and no extraneous code.
3. Then you refactor.

Until you get to the refactoring stage, you probably won't even have any private methods.

Answer (score 1):

You test the behavior of classes. Start with public method. If you cover **all states of the object** most likely you would cover the private methods. Aim for 100% **state coverage** ( just a mark. not really achievable in practical cases)

Comment: I will be awarding a bounty to this answer.  I wish more people thought like this.  Testing should be about checking that your class meets its requirements; not about what methods you've got.  If you build your methods, then look to test them, you run the risk of writing tests for functionality that you already know you've got; instead of writing tests for the functionality that you need.

Comment: I have awarded the promised bounty of 100 reputation points.  This formidable answer emphasises that we should test BEHAVIOUR, not methods.  It advises 100% state coverage (which is excellent); rather than 100% LOC coverage (which is both uneconomical and pointless).  I wish that more of the developers that I have encountered during my long career had Jayan's attitude towards unit testing.

Comment: @David Wallace : Thank you - added a stress on 'state coverage'- Hopefully it does not mix up with statement coverage :)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your goal of testing. 
Ideally you want to test all of them at 100% coverage :)

Comment: Sorry, but 100% LOC coverage isn't really a cost-effective way to test; and it by no means guarantees that the class does what it's supposed to.  It can, however, lead to a false sense of security.

Comment: it's also pretty much impossible in a real world application with a user interface - hence the smiley face. Set your goals high I say.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you are going to see a whole lot of private methods floating around, that being said, they will show up in a method where the variables involved should not be modified externally/outside of very specific circumstances. That being said, the main difference between public and private is accessibility: private can only be accessed within the class, whereas public can be accessed outside of the class.